# mysql error 1045(280000) access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint '@' localhost using password 'yes'

Tags: mysql

I edited deian.cnf to change the password of mysql (ubuntu server)

> sudo vi /etc/mysql/debian.cnf

I change

> user=debian-sys-maint password=*****

to

> user=debian-sys-maint
>
> password=mypassword

then I tried to enter console of mysql

> mysql -udebian-sys-maint -p

and inputed password 'mypassword'

it reported

```
mysql error 1045(280000) access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint '@' localhost using password 'yes'
```

I tried to remove mysql and reinstall, the error is same.

Your comment welcome

Comment: I think you need to tell mysql about the password change by also changing the password in mysql.

Answer (score 5):

The error message tell you that, your password is wrong or the account `debian-sys-maint` has no access to the database on host `localhost`.

If you are sure your password is correct you should grant all privileges like this:

login as root first

```
mysql -u root -p <password>
```

then, grant full permissions:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your password';
```

restart mysql and see if the error message is gone.

Answer (score 1):

By default root does not have a password and so you need not append -p at the end. simply type

**mysql -u root**.

To reset the password, use   **mysqladmin -u root password [newpassword]**

Answer (score 1):

Most easy way to restoring the debian-sys-maint user, is to reconfigure package mysql-server-5.5. That if you know the password for the root user of MySQL, you can try to restore the user and its password in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

NOTE: if you cannot stop mysql pid, just run `sudo killall mysqld`. This is needed for reconfiguring the mysql-server-5.5.